# How to get internal and external IP addresses

Tags: server, xubuntu, ip

I recently deployed a droplet on Vultr and I need to find the external and internal IP addresses. I have just one IP (which I presume to be the external IP or not).

How and/or where do I locate the two IPs?

The server is running Ubuntu.

Comment: `ifconfig` is your friend, that is, when Ubuntu runs on ...some hardware.

Comment: I would likely use `ip addr` (esp. if `ifconfig` is not installed)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a simple command to get all IP info, and it tells you if it's local (internal) or global (external)

Just run:

```
sudo ifconfig
```

And presto, you'll know all you wanted to and more

Answer (score 10):

To get your internet (WAN) IP address: `wget -qO- ifconfig.me/ip`

To get your internal (LAN) ip address(es): `ip addr | grep inet`

Comment: See also [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/22615/how-can-i-get-my-external-ip-address-in-a-shell-script) and [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/335371/how-does-dig-find-my-wan-ip-address-what-is-myip-opendns-com-doing#495954) answer on how to get your external (WAN) IP address, the IP of your router if you're using [NAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation).

Comment: Why does `wget -qO- ifconfig.me/ip` show me the public IP while the accepted answer, although using the same core command (`ifconfig`) does not have the needed IP in its output?

Answer (score 4):

From the command prompt, to find your internal IP address:

```
ip addr show
```

You may get a result something like:

```
3: wlp3s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 5c:c5:d4:0e:64:a6 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.0.11/24 brd 192.168.0.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute wlp3s0
       valid_lft 172442sec preferred_lft 172442sec
    inet6 2600:1700:xxxx:83d:b472:9320:xxxx:4df5/64 scope global temporary dynamic 
       valid_lft 604444sec preferred_lft 85834sec
    inet6 2600:1700:xxxx:83d:fb6b:19ca:xxxx:5e6/64 scope global dynamic mngtmpaddr noprefixroute 
<snip>
```

In this case, my IPv4 address, given by my router, is 192.168.0.11.

To find your public IP address:

```
curl https://ipinfo.io/ip
```

You should get a reply like:

```
1xx.140.129.95
```