# Several IP Addresses fetched with hostname -I

Tags: networking, ip, interface, hostname

Kubuntu 20.04 LTS is returning 2 IP addresses after `hostname -I`. The second one is probably from docker0 network interface, so no big worries about that. Problem is that first IP address which have form of regular public IP address is completely different from one that I retrieve from browser's api. Basically system shows 3 different IP addresses.

The one returned with Chrome is totally different from one at my network interface `wlp0s20f3` that is fetched from terminal. I am connected on Wifi network. What is the issue here?

Comment: Your ISP assigns you one IP address. This is what you see when you Google "what is my ip address". You may have multiple computers and devices connected to your WiFi router. The router assigns **internal** IP addresses to each of these devices and computers in your home network.  These internal IP addresses (typically 192.168.0/1.xxx) are meaningless outside your home network. `hostname -I` shows the local (aka internal) IP address.

Comment: @user68186 Thank you this was exactly the answer! Is there a reason why no command in terminal fetch me the assigned IP address?

Comment: You are most welcome. I will write a full answer with more explanation. Then you can accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Q: What is the issue here?

## A: There is no issue

This is how the internet and the home networking work.

Your Internet Service Provider (ISP) assigns you one IP address for the whole household. Typically this IP address is dynamically assigned. This means it can change anytime. This is what you see in Chrome when you Google "what is my IP address".

You may have multiple computers and devices connected to your WiFi router. The router assigns internal IP addresses to each of these devices and computers in your home network. These internal IP addresses (typically 192.168.0/1.xxx) are meaningless outside your home network.

You may think of these addresses to be like the names of rooms in your house, bedroom, kitchen, etc. If I mail you a letter with the address "kitchen", the post office will have no way to send it to you.

`hostname -I` shows the local (aka internal) IP address.

`wget -qO- ifconfig.me/ip` shows the external IP address.

Note, the `wget` command actually gets a web page you can visit: https://ifconfig.me/ip. There is no "internal" way to get your "external" IP address.

See [How to get internal and external IP addresses](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1153964/how-to-get-internal-and-external-ip-addresses) for more.

Hope this helps

Comment: That's was helpful, thank you.